# All files of the internal memory are duplicated on an LG G6

Tags: sd-card, lg, 7.1-nougat

I have an LG G6 (has Android 7.1. An update with Android 8.0 is announced but not avaliable yet) with an SD card. The SD card went corrupt for some reason and after a phone restart, all files in the internal memory are listed twice. Somehow, a virtual folder named /sdcard/ (locaded at /storage/emulated/) is created and just mirrors the internal memory. I did a factory reset and the problem was fixed, but the SD card went corrupt again and the issue re-emerged. Is there a way to fix it without having to do a factory reset again? I'm not sure if it is completely related to the existence of the actual SD card either.